# Symfony: hinclude table row from controller

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, dom

I want to include table rows via [hinclude](http://mnot.github.io/hinclude/).:

```
            <tbody>
            {% for bill in bills %}
                {{ render_hinclude(controller('xxx:Admin:renderRow', {'bid': xxx.id}), {'Default': '<tr><td colspan="10"><img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" /></td>'}) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

It works, but the loaded comment will be displayed above the table. I know that's a javascript based problem. Is there a simple way to tell hinclude where the row should been shown?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't close the <tr> tag in your default value....

Comment: Thats a mistake but no problem, because the default value will be replaced by the loaded content.